# Telerik Ajax UpdatePanel radgrid wait for page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, telerik

I am using a

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="AjaxUpdatePanel" runat="server">
```

to load a radgrid on the page

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="StatisticsGrid" runat="server">
```

that takes about 10 seconds to load, this is because it is loading a huge quantity of data from the database, but instead of loading the page and showing a "loading in progress" text or image it loads the page once the radgrid is ready, having a pageload of 10 seconds.
Do you know how I can avoid this and showing an elegant loading text/image ?
It should work also when rebinding the grid.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Telerik, I recommend the `RadAjaxLoadingPanel`:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" Skin="WebBlue">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>

<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="StatisticsGrid">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="StatisticsGrid"/>
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>

    <telerik:RadGrid ID="StatisticsGrid" runat="server">
         ...
    </telerik:RadGrid>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

So replace your `asp:UpdatePanel` for a `telerik:RadAjaxPanel`. (I always prefer to use all telerik controls since their examples and support team encourage that practice.)

Comment: And, in my opinion, 10 seconds is too slow nowadays, so if your requirements allow you to use it, you should use `RadGrid`'s `Paging` options.

Comment: Hello, just changing the asp:UpdatePanel to telerik:RadAjaxPanel did not work, it generates lots of errors in all the code inside the telerik tag

Comment: did you replace the `...` with your `RadGrid`'s columns?